# How to store strings (i.e. class constats) to keep them localizable?

Tags: php, design-patterns, localization

**Situation**
Assuming we have following class:

```
<?php
class User {
const STATUS_NEW = 0;
const STATUS_DELETED = 1;

public static $aStatuses = array(
  self::STATUS_NEW     => 'New',
  self::STATUS_DELETED => 'Deleted'
);

// ...
}
?>
```

**Question**
How to make string `New` and `Deleted` ready for localization (using gettext in example)?

**Possible solution?**

```
...
public static function getStatuses() {
  return array(
    self::STATUS_NEW     => _('New'),
    self::STATUS_DELETED => _('Deleted')
  );
}
```

but somehow I feel that there is some more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two serious ways:

1) using gettext and po-files you easily edit with po-edit

2) using arrays for lokalization:

```
// lang.english.php
$text_arr['new'] = "New"; 

// lang.german.php
$text_arr['new'] = "Neu";
```

And then include the user specified languagefile. In the code itself you only use the variable

For myself I prefer gettext and po-files over array as they are far more usable when handling languages. Especially your translater dont need to write sourcecode.

Both versions are almost the same in terms of performance. I read an article about that sime time ago. When Iam home tomorrow evening I can have a look into my browserbookmarks and post it here. Or you can google it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think you misunderstood it thought. I am using `gettext` - thing is that I cannot use any function (in this case gettext function) in constant declaration.